# How to Convert .Jpeg images to .Bmp

Tags: image, image-processing

I have JPEG images into my Local Drive. I want to Convert JPEG images to BMP and then apply a pallets to all Converted BMP images.

Please Suggest me What could be the Best way to Do this. pallets are the .pal files.

Comment: Niraj, is it mandatory to be done via VBA?

Comment: No, Currently i am using Photoshop Batch processing for converting jpg to Bmp,and Paint shop pro for Applying  Pallets to images. But the limitation for this is Paint shop Pro does not have batch processing

Comment: So are you looking for a VBA Solution?

Comment: Correct Because Converting Thousands of images into Bmps and Applying pallets is Time Consuming. I want to Automate this Process.

Comment: You can do this in VBA but VBA is not the Right Choice for this. Do you still want a VBA code?

Comment: What can be the Best way or Technology To Do this

Comment: @SiddharthRout: There is Difference Between the output of Irfanview and Paint shop pro. The imgages are blurred and not exact same as the Paint shop Pro.

Comment: In that case I would recommend you to wait for an Image expert to answer your question :) I have added the relevant tags :)

Answer (score 23):

Your best bet for converting images would be the command line tool [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). Your command would be something like:

```
mogrify -format bmp *.jpg
```

P.S. are you sure you want to convert to BMP? They take up a huge amount of disk space. If you want lossless compression you can use PNG.

Comment: And to add a bit:  PNG images can also be 8-bit, so can be paletted.